# Extracting specific parts of a line in a text file using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I am making software to help keep track of work hours for volunteers. Right now I have a text file (with the name the same as the volunteer) that I am logging the date and time every time a someone signs in or out, like this:

```
Sign In - 04/04/16 23:51:55
Sign Out - 04/05/16 00:09:48
Sign In - 04/05/16 00:09:55
```

But what i need to do is extract the date and time so i can say this volunteer worked x amount of hours on this date. This is what i have tried:

```
string datetimeStringDay1In = System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"C:/users/public/Volunteers/" + Form1.selectedUser + ".txt").Skip(23).Take(1).First();
int startPosDay1In = datetimeStringDay1In.LastIndexOf("Sign In - ") + "Sign In - ".Length + 10;
int lengthDay1In = datetimeStringDay1In.IndexOf("PM") - startPosDay1In;
string SignInDay1 = datetimeStringDay1In.Substring(startPosDay1In, lengthDay1In);
```

Then doing the same for the next signout line, then moving on to doing the math. As I am sure you are already thinking this takes forever to code and limits how many entries I can have. I need a better way. I am willing to try differnet file types as long as i can read the file outside the software incase something goes wrong. At some point I am going to use a database but as of right now this is a proof of concept. After I am able to prove this saves time, money, and for some people hair, I will. Thanks you for your help.

Comment: What is the question? I cant figure out.

Comment: is there always a Sign Out after a Sign In?

Comment: The only time there wont be a sign out after a sign in is if that person is currently signed in.

Comment: Why does this limit the number of entries?  Also do you just need to extract one specific date or the amount of time for all dates?  And do you have to deal with over night shifts that might start on one day and end on the next?

Comment: juharr,I would only be able to have the number of entries that I program for. The code that i pulled that sample from was over 150 lines long and took my over 4 hours to complete and only allowed 14 entries. The work times are from 8 am to 11 pm so overnight shifts aren't needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each line has both Sign In and Sign Out. Save the record in a csv file

```
04/04/16 23:51:55, 04/05/16 00:09:48
04/05/16 00:09:55
```

note the 2nd sign in has not signed out yet.

To parse this file

```
var records = System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"C:/users/public/Volunteers/" + Form1.selectedUser + ".csv");

foreach(var line in records) {
    var records = line.split(",")
    DateTime Time_in = DateTime.Parse(records[0]);
    if (records.length > 0) {
       DateTime Time_out = DateTime.Parse(records[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP said they have one file per user.  And this would require them to either wait for the sign out before writing or finding the sign in line and updating it which would complicate the process that is currently creating the file.

Comment: I didn't even know csv files existed. I guess that shows how much of a noob I am. Ill do some more research on how to do this. Thank you.

Comment: csv is a formatted text file. use a comma to separate columns.

Comment: This will work, just have a few kinks to work out. Your code wasn't exactly right but it pushed me in the right direction, thank you again.